# In Openmp, should omp_init_lock() and omp_destroy_lock() be called once per parallel region or once per program invocation?

Tags: c++, openmp

Consider the following piece of OpenMP code:

```
for(std::size_t i=0;i<numiter;i++)
{
  #pragma omp parallel 
  {
    omp_set_lock(&lck);
    //do something
    omp_unset_lock(&lck);
  }
}
```

According to the OpenMP spec `omp_init_lock(&lck)` and `omp_destroy_lock(&lck)` need to be called before and after a parallel region invocation. However in the above code can we call `omp_init_lock(&lck)` and `omp_destroy_lock(&lck)` outside the for loop or does it have to be called inside the for loop? In other words is the below code correct?

```
omp_init_lock(&lck);
for(std::size_t i=0;i<numiter;i++)
{
  #pragma omp parallel 
  {
    omp_set_lock(&lck);
    //do something
    omp_unset_lock(&lck);
  }
}
omp_destroy_lock(&lck);
```

or do I need to call those functions once per parallel invocation, ie:

```
 for(std::size_t i=0;i<numiter;i++)
    {
      omp_init_lock(&lck);
      #pragma omp parallel 
      {
        omp_set_lock(&lck);
        //do something
        omp_unset_lock(&lck);
      }
      omp_destroy_lock(&lck);
    }
```

Comment: It is enough to initialize only once, first code is OK.

Comment: both approaches are correct, however doing it once per program invocation is likely more efficient. Not using locks would be probably the most efficient :)

Comment: In addition to what the others said, if you use the lock in only one place, meaning it only protects a single segment of code, using ```#pragma omp critical``` clearer and easier to use, maybe even faster.

Answer (score 0):

`omp_init_lock` and `omp_destroy_lock` should be called when a lock is created (before it is first used) and when it is destroyed.

Since you are writing C++ this should be a simple concept, since it's saying that they should happen inside the (notional) constructor and destructor.

If you want to make that automatic, then write your own class to hold an `omp_lock_t` which makes those calls in its constructor and destructor, and then give it the methods you want to expose which invoke the relevant OpenMP methods on the embedded `omp_lock_t`.